# phpMyAdmin stopped working when accessed from a network computer

Tags: php, mysql, macos, phpmyadmin

Have had MySQL and PHP running under Mac OS X Server (El Capitan) for years, able to access phpMyAdmin from other machines on my LAN.

(To clarify: PHP and MySQL and phpMyAdmin run *only* on the El Capitan server. I use a web browser on other network machines to access phpMyAdmin.)

After a few months of not using phpMyAdmin, I now find that my laptop (MacBook Pro) will no longer load phpMyAdmin. It seems to be waiting forever for a response from the server.

I know PHP on the server is working and accessible because the laptop loads `info.php` with no problem, and phpMyAdmin works fine from `localhost`.

Maybe phpMyAdmin is having trouble making a database connection when accessed remotely?

AFAIK, the only change to the system during the period of non-use has been updating macOS to Catalina on the laptop.

Comment: Are you able to make connection with the PHP? I mean can you connect to the DB via `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: Sorry, don't understand the question. It works fine when working on the server machine.

Comment: Likely `updating macOS to Catalina`which may not work if the underlyings used `mysql_` functions (according to https://jasonmccreary.me/articles/update-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x-catalina/ `Catalina comes with PHP 7.3 pre-installed`) . `php --version` gives what from terminal? (`Mac OS X El Capitan comes pre-installed with PHP version 5.5`)

Comment: Question is very confusing. `able to access phpMyAdmin from other machines on my LAN.` Do you mean able to access databases on other servers using PHPMyAdmin on my mac?

Comment: I'm not using the laptop's PHP. I'm accessing PHP on the El Capitan server which has worked fine for years.

Comment: Did you install PHP on `El Capitan` or use native? Native is an older version

Comment: PHP version is 5.5.38. I don't remember whether it's native or updated; I think updated. If you have more questions, try www.froghill.net/info.php

Comment: `www.froghill.net` is running el captain which uses < 7. `Catalina` uses > 7, you likely need to upgrade your phpmyadmin version to one using `mysqli` or `pdo`. This is loosely a PHP question, but I don't use phpmyadmin so can't advise on version to go to.

Comment: PHP and MySQL run on the El Capitan server. Clients access phpMyAdmin on the server with a web browser—the client's version of PHP isn't relevant. Also I'm fairly sure phpMyAdmin already uses `mysqli`. IIRC it's a config option.

Comment: So `El Capitan` is running the `phpMyAdmin`? If that is the case than the Catalina update is irrelevant to the question. It sounded like you had `phpmyadmin` installed on mac, updated it, then it wouldn't connect to the `mysql` instance, which would have been explainable by PHP version update. I can't follow what system is doing what though.

Comment: The only client component is a web browser. Everything else is on the server. It's worked fine for years. Now it doesn't, unless I am working at the server, using its browser and running phpMyAdmin through localhost.

Comment: Update: I tried connecting to phpMyAdmin from a different Mac client on the same LAN. This client runs El Capitan (same as the server). It works. This would seem to increase the suspicion that there's something about Catalina (though again, the Catalina client just uses a web browser to access phpMyAdmin on the server—there is no dependence on the client's PHP.)